# How do I make sure when I save data to a csv it keeps the commas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I am try to pre-process some data while trying to learn machine learning. Right now im stuck as the data I want to save, I need to have the commas included in the saved csv file. How would I go along doing that

```
for x in X:
    for z in x:
        print(z)
        Z.append(z)
    V.append(Z)
    Z = []
    if i == 1:
        break
pd.DataFrame(V).to_csv("foo.csv")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If values of your data includes commas you have several options to store them:

1. Use `escapechar` to escape them.

```py
for x in X:
    for z in x:
        print(z)
        Z.append(z)
    V.append(Z)
    Z = []
    if i == 1:
        break
pd.DataFrame(V).to_csv("foo.csv", escapechar='\')
```

Don't forget to use it when loading the same file to avoid confusion

```py
df = pd.load_csv("foo.csv", escapechar='\')
```

2. Use another delimiter than a coma, for example a tab `\t` or pipe `|`

```py
for x in X:
    for z in x:
        print(z)
        Z.append(z)
    V.append(Z)
    Z = []
    if i == 1:
        break
pd.DataFrame(V).to_csv("foo.csv", sep='\t')
```

Please refer to [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html) for all related options.

3. Moreover, you don't have to use Pandas for such simple task as writing CSV files. You can use [csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module. Examples from the [tutorial](http://zetcode.com/python/csv/). This option is more complicated in the code, but more efficient as well.

```py
...
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    for row in V:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

You can register own dialect to use custom settings, for example:

```
csv.register_dialect("hashes", delimiter="#")
with open('foo.csv', 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, dialect="hashes")
    for row in V:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: it currently doesn't have commas, but I want to have commas included